# Executar comando PHP no CentOS 7 através do shell_exec()

Tags: php, linux, centos, exec

sou inciante em PHP, quero fazer uma página que dispara alguns comandos no servidor Linux.
(Ex.: através de um botão, executar um "service dhcpd restart" ou "./restart-tomcat.sh" 
Quando rodo essa aplicação no xampp (Windows), funciona de boa, abro a calculadora, bloco de notas e até lanço um ping dentro de uma div, como podem abaixo.

Mas quando coloco lá no Linux Centos7 em /var/www/html aquele campo onde deve aparecer o ping fica em branco e nenhum outro comando é executado.

Já dei as permissões para o apache lá no /etc/sudoers.

Será algo específico que precise mudar no código para rodar no Linux?

[HTML]


    
    
    Teste Servidor
    
        div {
            width: 500px;
            height: 200px;
            border: solid black;
            margin: 100px;
        }

```
    img{
        max-width: 500px;
        max-height: 200px;
    }
</style>
```

```
<button type="button" id="btn" onclick="geral()">Ping</button>

<div id="campo"></div>



<script>
    function geral() {

var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var campo = document.getElementById('campo');

xhttp.open("POST", "script.php", false);
xhttp.send();
// console.log(xhttp.responseText);
resposta = xhttp.responseText;

campo.innerHTML = resposta;

} 
</script>
```

[PHP]

**

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

$result = shell_exec('ping -c4 www.google.com.br');

echo '

```
'.$result.'
```

';

?>

Answer (score 0):

As vezes costumo usar o shell_exec + php, porém, uso mais em sistemas derivados do Debian. Para funcionar corretamente, muitas vezes preciso configurar as permissões do usuário que o php usa, acho que é o usuário www-data nos derivados do debian. De qualquer forma use:

```
$result = shell_exec('whoami');
```

Assim você deverá descobrir qual o usuário o php está usando e depois é só dar as permissões necessárias, se for o caso.